# How can I get usable unsigned 32 bit integer to work with?

Tags: javascript

It exists in array form as [Uint32Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint32Array) ( signed version is [Int32Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Int32Array) ), but I was told that once you access this value it becomes a normal JS number.

```
let number = (new Unit32Array(1)).fill(1)[0];
```

Where the variable number is implemented as a double and once you do a bitwise operation it is converted to a 32 bit signed integer.

I don't get the purpose of Unit32Array if you can actually use the un-signed representation in the array, i.e. once you access it, it pops out at a normal number?

```
function analyze () {
  // let test = 2147483647; // max 32 bit integer
  // let test = -2147483647; // min 32 bit integer
  for(let place = 0; place < 32; place++){
    let power2 = Math.pow(2, place);
    let bit = test & power2;
    console.log(place, bit)
  }
}
analyze();

/*
2^0 is 1 is 0x1
2^1 is 2
2^2 is 4
2^3 is 8
.
.

2^31 is 2147483648
2^32 is 4294967296
*/
```

Comment: uint is unsigned int. Unit32Array is an array of unsigned ints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most people are not aware that JavaScript works well with bit-wise operations.  You need to pair it with an [array buffer](https://javascript.info/arraybuffer-binary-arrays) however.

```
let buffer = new ArrayBuffer(16); // create a buffer of length 16

let view = new Uint32Array(buffer); // treat buffer as a sequence of 32-bit integers
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the triple right shift to use a number as unsigned. It essentially prevents sign-extension (and it works with Uint32Array).

```
 > var myNumber = -5;
-5
> myNumber >>> 0
4294967291
```

Comment: That is a cool trick.   You are just converting the sign bit to a value bit so 2^32 is 4294967296

Comment: and leaving the 5 in place ... so the 96 and not 91 ending.